# package javax.ejb does not exist inspite of jar file in classpath

Tags: java, compilation, ejb, javac

I'm trying to compile a java program using command

```
javac -d build src/*.java -verbose
```

It returns me the following:

```
src\Currency.java:5: package javax.ejb does not exist
import javax.ejb.*;
^
src\Currency.java:7: cannot find symbol
symbol: class EJBObject
public interface Currency extends EJBObject {
                              ^
```

I'm using jdk1.6.0_35.
CLASSPATH contains C:\wls1036_dev\modules\ which contains javax.ejb.jar

What could possibly be the problem?

Comment: The caret in the last line is actually not below extends but below the E of EJBObject.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem .

You need to add `javaee5.jar` to you class path .

For example I imported an ejb project and then realised I was using a version of Netbeans that did not have the EJB & EAR support . So i downloaded the plugin . After doing that the javaee5.jar was present at C:\Users\sjauhar\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.3.1\modules\ext . Added it to my project and the error went away .

Comment: Pode ser adicionado diretamente ao projeto em Bibliotecas!

Answer (score 0):

The classpath must contain the full path to each jar file you want included, not just the folder in which your jar files exist. So, for example, add

> C:\wls1036_dev\modules\javax.ejb.jar

to your classpath

Comment: Tried both. No luck :(

[Screen shot of error](http://www.flickr.com/photos/12284660@N08/8083707468/in/photostream)

Comment: looks like you added it to the 'sourcepath' instead of the 'classpath'

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally compile using the JDK provided by WebLogic, rather than using the J2SE bin and libs.