# Ant build failing when upgrading to weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, ant, weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

We have an existing application which has an ANT script used for deployment and running on weblogic version 9.2.3.

We had a request to upgrade the weblogic to version 12.1 and I was able to successfully upgrade this by changing the application specific WL_HOME and giving the build using the ANT script already present. But unfortunately we were having a dependency on another application that is running on weblogic 8.1 and weblogic 12.1 is not compatible with 8.1.

So we are now in the process of downgrading the weblogic to version 10.3.6 and after installation of weblogic 10.3.6, I changed the same application specific property WL_HOME to point to weblogic 10.3.6 and tried the ANT build.

But this time the ANT script failed, throwing errors saying error: **package javax.ejb does not exist
import javax.ejb.CreateException;**

The application and weblogic is installed in a solaris/unix machine and we are using jdk 1.7.0.60 for the application.

I am not an expert on weblogic or ANT, and I couldn't figure out where I went wrong. I see that we have javax.ejb_3.0.1.jar present in the modules directory.

It will be really grateful if somebody could let me know where I might have gone wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you added `WL_HOME\modules\javax.ejb.jar` to classpath ?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875479/package-javax-ejb-does-not-exist-inspite-of-jar-file-in-classpath ? Seems like your class path is still wrong

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I found that I have the weblogic.jar added to my compile class path of ANT. I didn't have to add the javax.ejb.jar specifically as weblogic.jar used to automatically include this internally.
As per your suggestion I tried adding the javax.ejb.jar to the Compile class path of ANT and it went past the error where the build was failing. But it did fail soon enough saying java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/compiler/Tool
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: But I didn't face these issues with weblogic 12.1 or 9.2.3 versions which are already installed. So I just renamed the existing weblogic.jar in 10.3.6 folder to bkup_weblogic.jar and copied the weblogic.jar from the 12.1 version and put it in servers/lib folder of 10.3.6 and tried the build. It went smoothly without any issues.

So I think the real problem is there is something wrong with the weblogic.jar which was available in the 10.3.6. Do you think it would have been caused by some installation issues? Or what else would have caused it?